# Can I listen to website url host? Node JS

Tags: node.js, http, url, server

I can't understand one thing- does NodeJS allow to listen to custom hostname? Not localhost. Because when I listen to my website url (example.com), I'm getting the following error:

> Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL *example.com ip-address*:1000 at
>   Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11) at
>   exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1045:20) at Server._listen2
>   (net.js:1246:19) at listen (net.js:1295:10) at net.js:1405:9 at
>   _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:77:11) at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9) at
>   Module.runMain (module.js:606:11) at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7) at
>   startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)

Why does it happend? And can I listen for POST messages from external site URL?

Comment: If `example.com` resolves to the IP of the machine you are running this server, then you should be able to listen on `example.com`. Please check which address `example.com` resolves to in your case.

Comment: It isn't. Ip of example.com and Ip of my machine are different. So there is no way to listen to example.com from my local machine?

Comment: then no. You can only listen to an address (or a domain name pointing to an address) that is on your machine.

Comment: you only needed this for your local testing ?

Answer (score 0):

> Why does it happend?

This happens because the `hostname` and `port` you requested isn't available to you.

> can I listen for POST messages from external site URL?

No, You can't. [server.listen()](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen_port_hostname_backlog_callback) accepts `hostname` and `port`

> Begin accepting connections on the specified port and hostname. If the hostname is omitted, **the server will accept connections on any IPv6 address (::) when IPv6 is available**, or any IPv4 address (0.0.0.0) otherwise. Omit the port argument, or use a port value of 0, to have the operating system assign a random port, which can be retrieved by using server.address().port after the 'listening' event has been emitted.

And further digging into [list of Node.js **Common System Errors** docs](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors) and [exhaustive list](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html), It is clear that, `Address not available` was the case.

> EADDRNOTAVAIL   Address not available (POSIX.1).